# Using Scenario Outline and Examples with Strings

Tags: cucumber-jvm

I'm facing the following "issue" when trying out cucumber-jvm with an Arabic to Roman Numeral converter - the "then" piece gets converted into several step defs instead of one.
here's my scenario outline:

```
Scenario Outline:
Given a romanizer
When I romanize <arabic number>
Then I get the <roman numeral>

Examples:
| arabic number | roman numeral |
|             1 |             I |
|             2 |            II |
|             3 |           III |
|             4 |            IV |
|             5 |             V |
|             6 |            VI |
|             7 |           VII |
|             8 |          VIII |
|             9 |            IX |
|            10 |             X |
```

For this, i was expecting the then stepdef to simply be:

```
I_get_the(String value)
```

but instead it turns it into one stepdef for each example:

```
I_get_the_I()
I_get_the_II()
```

etc.
what am i doing wrong?
Thanks,
Nilesh

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use (note the double quotes)

```
Scenario Outline:
  Given a romanizer
  When I romanize "<arabic number>"
  Then I get the "<roman numeral>"
```

Comment: worked brilliantly for me :) didn't need the quotes around the <arabic number> since it was already working. adding the quotes around <roman numeral> did the trick. on a related note, where is this info? in the cukes.info docs? i couldn't find it.

Comment: @Bala: That's better.  I didn't notice the single quotations around the query.  I mistakenly flagged your post and I apologize.  Also, thank you for adding clarification at the beginning of your post